# Can't connect to my own hostname

Tags: routing

When I connect to my VPN, I can't access my own hostname.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping my-laptop
Pinging my-laptop [172.25.224.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
...
```

The address `172.25.224.1` is the IP address of one of my interfaces, but since the VPN routes all traffic through HQ, obviously I can't access it.

#### Can I change the IP that my hostname is being resolved to?

I tried adding an entry in the hosts file, but it doesn't help. Probably because [`getaddrinfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) returns all local IP addresses before DNS entries.

#### Can I add a route to override this?

After adding some routes, this is the relevant part of my route table:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetRoute | Where DestinationPrefix -Like "172.25.224.*"
ifIndex DestinationPrefix    NextHop        RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------    -------        ----------- -------- -----------
71      172.25.224.2/32      0.0.0.0                  2 15       ActiveStore
71      172.25.224.1/32      0.0.0.0                  1 15       ActiveStore
7       172.25.224.0/21      172.16.10.26             1          ActiveStore
71      172.25.224.0/20      0.0.0.0                256 15       ActiveStore
```

But here are the actual routes chosen:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 172.25.224.1 | Select DestinationPrefix, NextHop
DestinationPrefix NextHop
----------------- -------
172.25.224.0/21   172.16.10.26

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 172.25.224.2 | Select DestinationPrefix, NextHop
DestinationPrefix NextHop
----------------- -------
172.25.224.2/32   0.0.0.0
```

Why is the route I added for `172.25.224.2` working but the route for `172.25.224.1` not?

Why is `172.25.224.0/21` selected over `172.25.224.0/20` even though the latter is more specific?

Comment: What VPN client are you using? Some of them play with more things than just routes (e.g. adding hidden firewall rules).

Comment: @user1686 I'm using Check Point. My Windows firewall is disabled by the system administrator, probably because I have Avast installed. I've been able to access my Hyper-V VM (where I also had the same issue initially) after adding some routes, but I guess it's technically possible. Do you have an idea how I can corroborate that?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you need to access your own host using your LAN address **instead of using** `localhost` **or** `127.0.0.1` while connected to the VPN?

It may not be possible.

> There is a security feature in almost all VPN configurations that
> blocks all local network connections while connected to the corporate
> network, via a VPN. This is to provide some degree of security by
> preventing someone with malicious intent from reaching the corporate
> server using your PC/Laptop as a stepping stone.

Reference Article: [https://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/02/21/access-local-and-vpn-network-simultaneously/#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20security%20feature,Laptop%20as%20a%20stepping%20stone](https://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/02/21/access-local-and-vpn-network-simultaneously/#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20security%20feature,Laptop%20as%20a%20stepping%20stone).

The article continues:

> In order to simultaneously access the local and remote VPN network you
> need to enable a feature called split-tunneling....If you have an
> Enterprise VPN solution such as Cisco, Watchguard, Sonicwall, or
> others, **an end user cannot enable split-tunneling. It is managed by
> the VPN appliance and will require the administrator to configure and
> enable if they see a need to do so.**

---

More info on Checkpoint and Split Tunneling: https://community.checkpoint.com/t5/Remote-Access-VPN/Split-Tunnel/td-p/34675

---

**EDIT: If your administrator has set** `Route all traffic to gateway` **as** `Configured on endpoint client`**, you can uncheck it in your own checkpoint settings. If it is grayed out, then you cannot change it on your end. See [this image](https://community.checkpoint.com/legacyfs/online/checkpoint/64201_pastedImage_2.png):**

[image]

Comment: I some applications which talk to each other using the hostname and it's kind of hardcoded, for the purpose of this discussion.
I saw the checkbox you pointed out. It is greyed out, but NOT checked for me.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really care what the VPN designer has planned for me :) I'm asking from a technical point of view, how I can get around this and why my route changes didn't help